# Connecting to API with access token from IdentityServer - 401 Unauthorized response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a MVC project, an identityserver and and API.
I get the accesstoken from identityServer but when I try to make a GET request to my API I get reponse 401 Unauthorized. What have I done wrong?

**This is my code for IdentityServer:
startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        
        if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
        else
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;


                options.ClientId = "xxxx";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxx";

                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-google";
            }).AddFacebook(facebookOptions => 
            {
                facebookOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                facebookOptions.ClientId = "xxx";
                facebookOptions.ClientSecret = "xxx";
                facebookOptions.ReturnUrlParameter = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook";
            });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
}
```

**Config.cs file:**

```
 public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
              new IdentityResource[]
              {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
              };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new ApiScope[]
        {
            new ApiScope("api1", "my API")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
           
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5002/signout-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1" 
                }
            }
        };
}
```

**Code for API project**
**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        // accepts any access token issued by identity server
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerAddress"];
                //options.Authority = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        // adds an authorization policy to make sure the token is for scope 'api1'
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api1");
            });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope");
        });
    }
}
```

**IdentityController**

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
}
```

**MVC-client**
**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            //options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

            options.Authority = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net";
            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
                .RequireAuthorization();
        });
    }
}
```

**After I successfully log in, I call this method:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        

        try
        {
            var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://xxx/identity");
            ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return View("json");
    }
```

When this method is called I get an 401 unauthorized error when I call client.getstringasync.

Comment: Hi, What if you remove `.RequireAuthorization("ApiScope")` in your api project.

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't work unfortunately! @rena

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?